# MacBook Air High Sierra disk image not recognised couldn't open

Tags: disk-utility, folders, error, mount, disk-image

I created a disk image from a folder using disk utility and now when I double click it to open it i get an error message saying image couldn't be opened. Image not recognised. What can I do?

Comment: Did you test it at the time? Has it worked since & suddenly failed?

Comment: Create another one and see if it does the same thing.

Comment: It could be corrupted. Follow @SteveChambers advice and create another one.